# Removing some labels from PlotLabels

Tags: labeling

How can I remove the labels of some of the curves in Plot? For example in the following plot, how can I remove labels for the first two curves? (removing MSC=0 and MSC=0.06 and keep the rest.)

```
gamma4 = .4; gamma3 = .284; gamma2 = .265; gamma1 = .484; z3 = 10000; \
z2 = 32000; z1 = 75000; zbar4 = 4800; zbar3 = 20050; zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100; h4 = .301; h3 = .404; h2 = .25;
h1 = .045; p1 = 3.89; p2 = 4.92; p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39;

g1 = 0;
g2 = 0.44;
g3 = 0.88;
g4 = 1.76;


Clear[\[Tau]2]

Cost2 = (g2 + 
      MSC (g1 p1 h1 + g2 p2 (h2 - 1) + g3 p3 h3 + 
         g4 p4 h4)) h2 (zbar2 - z2) + (g1 + 
      MSC (g1 p1 (h1 - 1) + g2 p2 h2 + g3 p3 h3 + g4 p4 h4)) h1 (z1 - 
      z2) - (MSC (g1 p1 h1 + g2  p2 (h2 + (1 - \[Tau]2)/\[Tau]2) + 
        g3 p3 h3 + g4 p4 h4)) h2 zbar2 gamma2 (\[Tau]2/(1 - \[Tau]2));
Gain2 = h2 (zbar2 - z2) + h1 (z1 - z2) - 
  h2 zbar2 gamma2 (\[Tau]2/(1 - \[Tau]2))


d7 = Show[
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost2, {MSC, {0,  0.06, 1, 2, 100}}], {\[Tau]2, 
    0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.15}, {0, 11000}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 
   PlotLabels -> 
    Placed[Table[
      StringForm["MSC\n=``.", MSC1], {MSC1, {0, "", 1, 2, 100}}], 
     Top]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
d7 = Show[
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost2, {MSC, {0, 0.06, 1, 2, 100}}], {\[Tau]2, 
    0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.15}, {0, 11000}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 
   PlotLabels -> 
    Placed[{"", ""}~Join~
      Table[StringForm["MSC\n=``.", MSC1], {MSC1, {1, 2, 100}}], 
     Top]]]
```

Comment: One would think that `{None,None}` instead of `{"",""}` would also work, but it does not, becuase `Placed` does not respect `None`, though it probably (?) should.